# Is there any way to show a counter of an element in a template in DJANGO?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to achieve something:

I have a sidebar template that is always in the screen:

base.html includes sidebar.html

There is a menu in that sidebar and one of the elements is "Pendant consumptions".

The thing is that I want some kind of badge with the number of pendant consumptions in that menu element, like this:

[image]

I know I could achieve this easily with ajax but I think that there must be a better way with Django.
The only way I know would be calling the same function (count_consumptions, for example) in all the views but that would be sooo weird.

Can you help me guys?

Comment: are you rendering it using a for loop?

Comment: No no, I just added it using the chrome developer tool, when I refresh it is not there

Comment: You can use templatetags (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write [custom context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors). For example, write a context processor file in `your_app/context_processors/pendant_count.py` file:

```
def pendant_count(request):
    return {'pendant_count': Pendant.objects.filter(user=request.user).count()}
```

Then add it to `context_processors` in settings.py:

```
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'your_app.context_processors.pendant_count',
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    }
```

And add the context processor in template:

```
{{ pendant_count }}
```

Comment: Oh wow I didn't know about this feature, seems so useful, let me give it a try!